# Can't resolve context for picasso in android

Tags: android, picasso, android-viewholder

I have a custom adapter that has data from json including a image url. The issue is I am getting "can't resolve symbol" on the context value inside the `onBindViewHolder()` ...

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    ClubFieldsModel value = Items.get(i);
    //Uri uri = Uri.parse(value.getFieldImageThumb().toString());
    viewHolder.title.setText(value.getTitle());
    viewHolder.desc.setText(value.getDesc());
    String imageUrl = value.getFieldImageThumb();

   //context "can't resolve symbol" error ...
   Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(viewHolder.field_image_thumb);

}
```

Can't see why the issue would exist, everything is initialized..

**EDIT: Full Adapter Code..**

```
package app.sync.myapp.adapters;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;


import app.sync.myapp.R;
import app.sync.myapp.model.ClubFieldsModel;

import static android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.action_context_bar;
import static android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.image;
import static app.sync.myapp.R.id.field_image_thumb;

public class ClubFieldsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClubFieldsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<ClubFieldsModel> Items;

public ClubFieldsAdapter(List<ClubFieldsModel> Items) {
    this.Items = Items;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.club_fields_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    ClubFieldsModel value = Items.get(i);
    //Uri uri = Uri.parse(value.getFieldImageThumb().toString());
    viewHolder.title.setText(value.getTitle());
    viewHolder.desc.setText(value.getDesc());
    String imageUrl = value.getFieldImageThumb();

     Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(viewHolder.field_image_thumb);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Items.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView field_image_thumb;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView desc;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        field_image_thumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.field_image_thumb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your full code of adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `viewHolder.itemView.getContext()`, where itemView is view you inflated `onCreateViewHolder`. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#itemView). E.g.

```
 Picasso.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext()).load(imageUrl).into(viewHolder.field_image_thumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso — Adapter Use (ListView, GridView, ...)
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-adapter-use-for-listview-gridview-etc

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to send the context to the adapter's constructor. Change it to:

```
private Context context;

public ClubFieldsAdapter(List<ClubFieldsModel> Items, Context context) {
this.Items = Items;
this.context = context;
}
```

And add the context, when you are call the Adapter Class.